# Error while entering input using bufferedreader in java

Tags: java, bufferedreader, stringtokenizer, inputstreamreader

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class GFG {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws  java.lang.Exception {
        //code
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
        int qu=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        while(qu-- >0)
        {
            int n=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            String[] s = br.readLine().trim().split("\\s+"); 
            int arr[]=new int[n];
            long prod=1;
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
             {arr[i]=Integer.parseInt(s[i]);
              prod*=arr[i];
             }
             for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
             {
                 System.out.print(prod/arr[i]+" ");
             }
            System.out.println();
            
            
        }
    }
}
```

This is my code and I want to give this as my input:
(I am using \n to show "enter" key)
1 \n 5 \n 10 3 5 6 2

and  I am getting this exception:

Runtime Error:

Runtime ErrorException in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "10 3 5 6 2"
at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
at GFG.main(File.java:15)

Comment: You already read the first line of input when you initialized your `StringTokenizer` (which you never use by the way). Therefore the next line read will be your `int qu`, which will be 5. After that, you try to parse the whole String `10 3 5 6 2` into your `int n`. This doesn't work and will throw the `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: You should try to get used to using a Debugger to debug your applications. There are plenty of tutorials online on how to do that. This will help you find bugs like these easier and faster in the future.

Comment: Thanks @maloomeister, now It is working